# Redirection not working

Tags: asp.net

I have an asp.net application running on integrated pipeline and I have this specified in the web.config:

```
<customErrors mode="On">

  <error statusCode="404" redirect="404Error.aspx" />

</customErrors>
```

However, my site still shows the generic 404 asp.net error.

Why is this?

Answer (score 1):

this will work for you

```
<customErrors mode="On">
  <error statusCode="404" redirect="http://www.easycomputerformat.com/404error.aspx" />
</customErrors>
```

try following too...

```
<error statusCode="404" redirect="~/404Error.aspx"/>
```

sample :

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <customErrors defaultRedirect="http://www.easycomputerformat.com/GenericError.htm"
                  mode="On">
      <error statusCode="404" redirect="http://www.easycomputerformat.com/404error.aspx"/>
      <error statusCode="403" redirect="http://www.easycomputerformat.com/403error.aspx"/>
    </customErrors>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Ok, this made it work, but now when i type http://www.easycomputerformat.com/dgdfgfdgfd.fdsgdfgdf (an extension other than .aspx) it doesnt work. Shouldnt integrated pipeline proccess all requests throu asp.net?

Comment: it is `HTTP Error 403 (Forbidden)` you can give another url for this also

Comment: "it is HTTP Error 403 (Forbidden) you can give another url for this also" I fixed  that, was a problem with IIS and default start page. Please see my edit comment

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the 404Error.aspx file exist in the root of the application ?

Answer (score 0):

**redirect non aspx pages to error page**

you can set custom error page for IIS by setting 404 error page for your virtual directory